# Obtain custom cell format notation as text

Tags: excel

I have a column containing quantities. Along with these quantities there is a unit of measure displayed, such as KG, or L. However this isn't hard copied text but rather some custom formatting rule, for example #.##0 "L". What I would like is to extract these UOMs into their own seperate column as text. Is there some way I can access these formatting rules to do this or is there some other method that will get me what I want?

My solution for completeness.

```
Function getcellformat(ByRef valuecell As Range) As String

    getcellformat = Replace(Split(valuecell.NumberFormat, " ")(1), Chr(34), "")

End Function
```

Thanks to teylyn for pointing out the .NumberFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.NumberFormat` property to show the number format applied to a specific cell

Here's a screenshot from the Immediate Window for the Number Format of cell A1 of the current sheet

[image]